# Move the mouse without clicking using a touchscreen

Tags: windows, touchscreen

In many occasions you have to move the mouse over an area of the screen or an element in an interface without clicking on it.

is there a way to achieve this?

I use windows 8.1 on a Lenovo Yoga Pro 2 with a touchscreen. I already managed to remap the windows key to a right mouse button with AutoHotkey, but that's another question.

Maybe it would be possible to catch a gesture or something like that, that would disable the clicking of the mouse when you move the finger over the touchscreen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two Windows features which may solve your problem.

1. The pointer option on Windows Vista and 7. It appears that it is gone in Windows 8.
2. Another option to move the pointer is using Mouse Keys.
   Go to `Control Panel`->`Ease of Access`->`Ease of Access Center`->`Make the mouse easier to use` and there is an option called 'Mouse Keys'. It's pretty self-explanatory.

**This program may be the solution:**
[TouchMousePointer](http://www.lovesummertrue.com/touchmousepointer/en-us/) - its a virtual touchpad. (Here is [some Discussion about the program.](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-hardware/enable-mouse-pointer-on-windows-8-tablet/edfd0711-7731-451c-83cd-372d0096eec8?page=2))

Comment: Mouse Keys will controll the mouse with a Numpad, If you have one, which is not the question here. I want to controll the mouse with my touchscreen without clicking the mouse on every touch

Comment: TouchMousePointer seems to solve this.